# construct a dynamic url using path variables in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, querystringparameter, spring-config

i would like to generate a dynamic url like 
http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple

where i can send name and color two separate input fields from my form to controller as a single parameter.
can someone please help me with the corresponding jsp and spring controller coding.

the following is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws/jobs/{title}/{location}/{experience}")
     public ModelAndView openRequirementsRedirect(JobSearchRequest jobSearchRequest) throws Exception{
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
         model.addObject("title", jobSearchRequest.getTitle());
     model.addObject("location", jobSearchRequest.getLocation());
     model.addObject("experience", jobSearchRequest.getExperience());
     model.setViewName("openJobs/openjobs");
     return model;
}
```

i am having pojo :

```
public class JobSearchRequest {
    private String title;
    private String location;
    private String experience;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }
    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }
}
```

and  y jsp call is something like this :

```
window.location.href = example+"/abc?&title="+title+"&location="+location+"&experience="+experience;
```

Comment: The example URL you arr giving in the JavaScript snippet doesn't match the URL path in your controller annotation.

Comment: can you please let me the know the right javascript code for my above controller Mike.

Comment: It would be something like:

`window.location.href = "/ws/jobs/"+title+"/"+location+"/"+experience;`

assuming title, location, and experience are some variables you get somewhere before

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/project/{projectId}/{bookmark}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody boolean bookmarkProject(@PathVariable("projectId") UUID projectId,
                                             @PathVariable("bookmark") boolean bookmark) {
    return userService.bookmarkProject(projectId, bookmark);
}
```

Comment: but this will create my url as  http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret/color=purple  but i need the name and color as a single parameter separated by &

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying the read query param, so, you have to use @RequestParam annotation to the api method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws/jobs/{title}/{location}/{experience}")
public ModelAndView openRequirementsRedirect(   JobSearchRequest jobSearchRequest,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false, value = "name") String name,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false, value = "color") String color
 ) throws Exception{

     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
     model.addObject("title", jobSearchRequest.getTitle());
     model.addObject("location", jobSearchRequest.getLocation());
     model.addObject("experience", jobSearchRequest.getExperience());
     model.setViewName("openJobs/openjobs");
     return model;
}
```

The above method will work if the resource url would be

http://example.com/title1/loc1/exp1?name=ferret&color=purple